# SMTP connection failing problem

Tags: smtp

Just want to throw this question here so the answers can be easily found by people who met similar problems.

Problem came up when we were trying to test some new mailing services with CiviCRM 4.7, we kept getting "connection refused" errors and other similar messages with different protocols and ports entered in outbound mail settings.

The environment we have: Ubuntu 14.04, php 5.6, Drupal 7.3.x, CiviCRM 4.7.x.

Comment: A [duplicate over here](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9467/outbound-mail-fails-after-upgrading-to-4-7-1?lq=1)?

Comment: Disabling SSL peer verification is, to me, like taking the bulb out of a warning light to "fix" a problem with your engine. Please get the underlying issue fixed instead 

Answer (score 15, accepted):

PHP5.6 has [enabled peer verification by default from 5.6.x](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.openssl.php). The most likely cause of this issue is that **the SMTP server's SSL cert does not validate against the certs available to the hosting environment**.

So, on PHP5.6+, an SMTP connection via SSL and TLS will fail in CiviCRM ***if the certificates are not peer verified***. This is an issue either with the SMTP provider or your hosting environment's CA chain.

It is recommended instead to **resolve the underlying issues with your hosting/SMTP service**, but if you want to connect to a server with a self signed certificate (for example) you can patch CiviCRM to bypass this verification.

Change in packages/Net/SMTP.php

line `$this->_socket_options = $socket_options;`

to `$this->_socket_options = array('ssl' => array('verify_peer_name' => false));`

Updated: I have updated the comment here since the summary in the [ref link](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.openssl.php) has also been updated to include:

> While not recommended in general, it is possible to disable peer certificate verification for a request by setting the verify_peer context option to FALSE, and to disable peer name validation by setting the verify_peer_name context option to FALSE.

The above works around the problem with SMTP failure however it is better to ensure the server is set up with valid SSL certificate and configurations.

Comment: Are you sure all SMTP using TLS will fail, or just those using self-signed certificates which fail peer validation? Or hosting environments with outdated CA on the server.

Comment: Works for me with SMTP via GMail. Thanks!

Comment: I just ran into this as well. Should we be pushing to get this into core?

Comment: Same here, ran into this issue with MailGun.  The above fixed it for me.

Comment: With CiviCRM 4.7.15 and Joomla, I had to apply the single line patch to make this work with PHP 5.6, connecting to Sparkpost. Confused why this is still an outstanding issue after almost a year?

Comment: Ditto here (CiviCRM 4.7.17/Joomla and PHP 5.6) - why is this not part of core? Been patching every silly CiviCRM upgrade ... sigh.

Comment: "Since php has enabled peer verification by default from 5.6.x, all the SMTP connection via SSL and TLS will fail in CiviCRM." <-- Not true! If the certificates have been set up properly peer verification should pass.

Comment: IMO this answer is bad advice (telling people to disable builtin security functionality to avoid hearing about issues in the hosting / SMTP environment). Since it has lots of upvotes, I've modified it to nudge people to a better solution, without wholesale rewriting the answer. I recommend people use Michael's solution instead.

Comment: Can anyone elaborate on what I need to do to solve this problem?  I am running CiviCRM 4.7.18 on Drupal 7, newly installed Ubuntu 16.04 running php 5.6.x.  I am getting the error:

Failed to connect to tls://smtp.sparkpostmail.com:587 [SMTP: Failed to connect socket: (code: -1, response: )]

Yes, we are connecting to sparkpost.  I tried prepending tls:// to the host as well as without.  None of my other web apps - including drupal itself - have a problem with 5.6.

Comment: We have tried to actively and passively solve this error with our mail provider, but we have always had the same answer saying that for its part everything was fine and that we should to deactivate this option by code.

Answer (score 7):

I had to go this far...

```
$this->_socket_options = array('ssl' => array('verify_peer'=>false,'verify_peer_name'=>false,'allow_self_signed'=>true));
```

Comment: FWIW, if you are connecting to well known third party mail provider, then it's highly likely that they have their certificates set up properly and you shouldn't need to disable peer verification.

Answer (score 6):

If you are connecting to well known third party mail provider, then it's highly likely that they have their certificates set up properly and ***you shouldn't need to disable peer verification***.

Check two things:

1. As it mentions on the *Settings - Outbound Mail* form, 'if the server uses SSL, add "ssl://" to the beginning of the server name'.
2. Check what port you are using: "The most common SMTP port possibilities are 25, 465, and 587".

And if the above does not resolve the issue, verify that the hosting environment's CA chain is up to date, since that will also trigger this problem.

*Note: In the case of Mandrill, even though the https://mandrillapp.com/settings page specified port 587, ssl only worked on port 465 (as explainined in [this mandrill knowledge base article](https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582177-Does-Mandrill-support-SSL-)).*

Comment: 3. verify that the hosting environment's CA chain is up to date, since that will also trigger this problem

Comment: PS. Yours is the correct answer, but the one recommending to disable peer verification has lots of votes 

Comment: Plus a zillion for not disabling peer verification! To speak directly to an example comment above our cert, ports, etc are set up properly and we have never had an issue connecting with Sparkpost using php 5.6.3.

Comment: @chris and eli - might want to consider voting up the comments in the wrong answer as well so they are above the comment fold to help others.

Comment: @EliLisseck how are you connecting to Sparkpost? I'm trying to figure out why it's not working for us. We're using Sparkpost, Let's Encrypt, and the PESC Sparkpost extension. The extension builders say it's a core Civi issue: https://github.com/proexchange/com.pesc.sparkpost/issues/22

Comment: @herb we are connecting via the Sparkpost API using civiCRM 4.7.15 with the Cividesk sparkpost extension (rather than pesc). There is a post somewhere about the comparison. We are on PHP 5.6.30 (mistype earlier) and it seems to be working fine. Our SSL cert is with GoDaddy. We are using their premium EV cert to get our name in the green box :). We've got email and DKIM verified. Hope that is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is some work in progress to attach this on [CRM-18408
SMTP connection via SSL and TLS in PHP 5.6](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18408)