# STARTTLS failed in version 4.7

Tags: civimail, 4.7

CiviMail throws the error `Mailing_send_test : STARTTLS failed` when doing a test email. Sending results in bounces. I have a handful of CiviCRM installations running on the same server and only 4.7 installs seem affected.

Version 4.6.9 no error. 
Version 4.7.3+ error as described.

Does anyone know what would have caused this?

(I did recently add mysqli per the recent blog post, and I went from PHP 5.5.38 to 5.6.24 in the process. But perhaps that's unrelated.)

Edit: I use CiviSMTP.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like it's the same problem [described here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/10964/smtp-connection-failing-problem/10966#10966).

While the solutions there suggest hacks to the code, most likely you're either a) connecting to a mail server that has a self-signed certificate, or b) your CiviCRM is installed on a server with an outdated list of CAs.  Fixing the root problem is preferable.  [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org) issues free SSL certificates in case your problem is the former one.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I tried the fix in the thread you referenced with no luck. So I reverted those changes then took the coward's way out and rolled PHP back to 5.5.38 which resolved the problem. I'll explore the rest of your advice in the meantime.

Comment: @EricH Do you have root access on the server your CiviCRM is hosted on?  If not, talk to your webhost!  If so - are you running an outdated version of your OS?  Also, if you're running FreeBSD, I think the CAs they ship with are out of date.

Comment: I have root access. It's running CentOS 6.8.