# How to resolve SMTP connection failing problem with code 535?

Tags: civimail, mailserver

After upgrading CiviCRM from 4.6 to 4.7.14 I was not able to send (test) emails via SMTP. I got the following error:

> authentication failure [SMTP: STARTTLS failed (code: 220, response: 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS)]

After replacing some code in `/packages/Net/SMTP.php` like [Matt](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/10981/123) suggested I'm now receiving the error:

> authentication failure [SMTP: Invalid response code received from SMTP server while sending email. This is often caused by a misconfiguration in Outbound Email settings. Please verify the settings at Administer CiviCRM >> Global Settings >> Outbound Email (SMTP). (code: 535, response: 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: authentication failure)]

Maillog says:

> Dec 21 11:19:55 rs0815 postfix/smtpd[31606]: warning: SASL authentication failure: client response doesn't match what we generated
>   Dec 21 11:19:55 rs0815 postfix/smtpd[31606]: warning: rs0815.rs.example.de[123.123.123.123]: SASL DIGEST-MD5 authentication failed: authentication failure

I doesn't make a difference if I use PHP 5.5 or 5.6.

Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: Can you provide more information?  E.g. are you prefixing your outgoing mail address with "ssl://"?  In Civi 4.7 you should remove that since it's technically incorrect; see https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-packages/pull/66

Comment: The SMTP-server is not prefixed with "ssl://", besides it is suggested in the input help: "If the server uses SSL, add 'ssl://' to the beginning of the server name[...]". It's just like smtp.example.com and port 25 with an authentication.

Comment: I've checked the log, see my updated question.

Comment: Hi Philipp, are you also the administrator of the SMTP server. The log suggests it is postfix. Maybe the post http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204515/postfix-with-smtp-authentication-failing offers some help. But it involves altering the configuration of postfix.

Comment: It's now working, but I don't know why. I didn't do anything conscious. So I'm still interested in a solution of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this very same problem with SMTP and couldn't find a solution with the configuration, although I didn't change the code you mention.
I found a workaround by choosing mail() instead of SMTP in Administer>system settings>outbound email, since when I've had no problems.  The default option should apparently work fine on linux systems, if that is appropriate.

Comment: Yes, I can send mails with the mail() function but I wan't to use a specific smtp server. So unfortunately this is no option.