# Email not working after upgrade to PHP 7.0

Tags: wordpress, email, 4.7, php7

WordPress 4.9.2
CiviCRM 4.7.29

I'm trying to upgrade to PHP 7 from 5.5, but CiviCRM mailer stops working. The Send test email results in:
[image]

To verify the email settings I used Easy WP SMTP 
[image]

And it is able to send a test email.
[image]

The server does not support SSL or TLS. Any ideas about what to try next?

Comment: Can you double check the port in the CiviMail, it looks to be set to 567 in the screenshots.

Comment: Thank you for noticing that. I'm getting authentication errors now in PHP 5.5.38. Does Settings - Outbound Mail reset the SMTP password if you change the configuration port or server?

Comment: I would reenter the password to be certain.

Comment: Yes authentication errors = wrong password.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that you've added (or removed) the `php-crypt` library in your PHP upgrade process.  This would cause your password to be encrypted in an incompatible method.  Re-enter your credentials or match your `php-crypt` to what it was previously.

Comment: If that were the case, why did Easy WP SMTP not have the same problem? This is not the first time I've had this problem.

Comment: If the problem is what I'm suggesting it is, then the issue isn't SMTP - it's how the credentials are stored in the database.  I have no idea how Easy WP SMTP stores its credentials in the database.

Comment: All other sites are working fine but currently it gives some error as "The e-mail could not be sent.
Possible reason: your host may have disabled the mail() function..."

Comment: @VishalKumarSahu That sounds like a different problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this answer](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/10964/smtp-connection-failing-problem/10966#10966) on the SE question **[SMTP connection failing problem](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/10964/smtp-connection-failing-problem)**. Seems related with your problem due to the PHP update above version 5.5.