# I can send emails with Drupal 7 using the SMTP Module but not CiviCRM

Tags: smtp

I host a server on Google Cloud with Protonmail Bridge running in the background. I am still new at working with CiviCRM 5.26.1 and PHP. I can successfully send emails via Drupal usinig the SMTP module but with CiviCRM I receive this error when I send a test email:

> authentication failure [SMTP: STARTTLS failed (code: 220, response: Ready to start TLS)]

In the [Bridge Configuration Guide](https://protonmail.com/bridge/thunderbird#11), an exception has to be set on Thunderbird.

Now, according to this solution that would seem to solve my problem : [SMTP connection failing problem](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/10964/smtp-connection-failing-problem), I don't have the same structure when I open the /Net/SMTP.php file.

Note: This exception is needed for Protonmail Bridge.

Comment: welcome to CiviCRM SE - well explained question - hopefully some one with mailing experience can answer soon

Answer (score 1):

Civicrm has changed how it's including the PEAR library - it was previously including a patched version - however this was updated in https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/commit/a6a0ff13d2a155ad962529595dceaef728116f96# to improve maintainability

I believe if you want to apply the fix from [SMTP connection failing problem](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/10964/smtp-connection-failing-problem)

you will now find the required file in vendor/pear/net_smtp/Net/SMTP.php