# How to configure CiviMail bounce processing with SMTP requiring login/sender check

Tags: mailing, smtp

We are experimenting with using our ISP:s SMTP host rather than PHP `mail()` to avoid getting caught in some spam-filters. The ISP is also the domain provider and handles DKIM when sending messages.

The SMTP setting test passes and sending individual mails also works. But Mailings are not sent. Trying a test mail (for an individual or group) announces "Sending... Delivered" and then a popup announces

> "Could not identify any recipients. Perhaps your test group is empty, or you tried sending to contacts that do not exist and you have no permission to add contacts."

It seems strange that it would first think that it had delivered it (got ok from SMTP server?) and then give that error message (is it even the correct one?)

Some [googling indicate](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/20856/354) that this is a random message that has nothing to do with the actual problem.

We are using Mosaico, CiviCRM 5.37.2.

Our ISP is requiring loggin in to the SMTP server with the senders email and also checks that the sender in the mail is that email address.

I'm thinking that the problem might be that the bounce processing changes the sender to the bounce address. Is there a way to confirm this? Log mail-sending errors in CiviCRM?

- Are there other possible reasons for this problem?
- Are there alternatives for mailing given our situation?

[EDIT] Sending single mails to contacts work. Reverting to `mail()` delivers the testmailing as it should.

Comment: is it sending single emails to individual contacts or not?

Comment: Yes, single emails directly to contacts work.

Comment: it sounds to me more like you may have some broken Smart Groups. have you tested by making a new standard Group with just yourself in it, and doing a civimail to it?

Comment: Yes. Same problem.

Comment: Have this same problem trying to setup for usage with AWS SES/SNS - seems that Test process is treating the sender email as recipient AND marking it as bounced.